# can a regex whitespace character cause an injection?

Tags: javascript, regex, security, code-injection

if I want to validate the input of a `<textarea>`, and want it to contain, for example, only numerical values, but even want to give users the possibility to insert new lines, I can selected wanted characters with a javascript regex that includes even the whitespace characters.

```
/[0-9\s]/
```

The question is: do a whitecharacter can be used to perform injections, XSS,even if I think this last option is impossible, or any other type of attack ?

thanks

Comment: You shouldn't run the input through a [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) interpreter I guess ;). Otherwise you're safe.

Comment: As a side point - if you want new lines, you should use "\n" instead of "\s" ... \s allows spaces and tabs, not just lines.

Comment: Tell us what you are doing with the string after validation! Where should something be injected?

Comment: the string has to be recovered via javascript, without the use of php, so in this case, server-side filters are not used, because the code is executed locally, not via a web server, I used activeX for this

Comment: Cross-post on Security.SE: [Can a whitespace regex character be used to perform a javascript injection?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/23741/539)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/[0-9\s]/` should be a safe whitelist to use, I believe. You do need to ensure that it checks the entire input, though; I think you mean `/^[0-9\s]*$/`.

Also remember, of course, that you have to validate it server-side, not just in the browser. Attackers can easily bypass JavaScript validation code.