# Can a whitespace regex character be used to perform a javascript injection?

Tags: javascript, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can a regex whitespace character cause an injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276474/can-a-regex-whitespace-character-cause-an-injection)

if I want to validate the input of a `<textarea>`, and want it to contain, for example, only numerical values, but even want to give users the possibility to insert new lines, I can selected wanted characters with a javascript regex that includes even the whitespace characters.

```
/[0-9\s]/
```

The question is: do a whitecharacter can be used to perform injections, XSS,even if I think this last option is impossible, or any other type of attack ?

thanks

**update**

yes I'm sorry for the duplicate, the question has been moved from webmasters site, it wasn't my intention to ask twice the same thing on the same site.

Comment: Highly unlikely I'd say, but impossible is nothing. You might want to be more strict and only accept newlines; who knows what funny Unicode characters might get matched by `\s`.

Comment: It depends on how this data is *used* afterwards. Just a whitespace character by itself will do nothing if you don't do anything with it, and it will also do nothing if you *handle it properly* wherever you are using it.